# Dynamic check of derived class type in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Platform class as a base class and there are 2 more classes IOSPlatform and AndroidPlatform that are derived from Platform.

In addition to this, there is a Device class that has Platform object as a navigation property.

While querying all IOS platform devices, the linq expression below is working like a charm.

```
devices.Where(t=> t.Platform is IOSPlatform)
```

I want to improve this query with making it dynamic check of class type such as:

```
Platform p = new IOSPlatform();
devices.Where(t=> t.Platform is /*derived class of p object*/)
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Best Regards,

Kemal

Comment: @AustinSalonen No, because it's not the type of the item variable `t`, it's the type of a member of `t`.

Comment: When we check the platform with IsAssignableFrom method it works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you want

```
devices.Where(t =>
    p.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(t.Platform.GetType())
    );
```

Comment: @kkocabiyik I'm always confused if it's `typeX.IsAssignableFrom(typeY)` or the other way round, `typeY.IsAssignableFrom(typeX)`, but this time I got it right.

Answer (score 4):

```
Platform p = new IOSPlatform();
devices.Where(t=> t.Platform.GetType()==p.GetType())
```

Comment: I think this is the answer but somehow entity framework is not giving me the results but thanks!

Comment: Hmm I realized that it is not about converting to list than querying. It is about while working with entity framework it creates dynamic proxies for each object. I checked the type of a particular platform object and it gave me the result something like System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IOSPlatform_19A9948583193035821BC32918BCEF4918DFD492C

Comment: (Read `(t.Platform)` for `x` in the following.) I thought the issue was: When `x` is a `DerivedPlatform`, and `p` is a `BasePlatform`, then `x.GetType() != p.GetType()` because one type is more derived than the other. So this is different than the `is` keyword. For both `x is DerivedPlatform` and `x is BasePlatform` evaluate to `true` since a `DerivedPlatform` is a `BasePlatform`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Platform p = new IOSPlatform();
devices.Where(t=> t.Platform.GetType().BaseType == p.GetType());
```

Comment: In this case you are checking the base type what we need to check is the derived type.

Comment: Infact the base type of t.Platform is the class from which it derives.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to verify if the object on your list inherits from Platform? The "is" operator already verifies that .. you could just use this:

```
devices.Where(d => d.Platform is Platform);
```

Or even use the OfType method:

```
devices.OfType<IOSPlatform>();
```

Comment: I actually try to get the devices in which their platform is IOSPlatform.

Comment: The second solution can only work if you know the type at compile so it's not "dynamic" in the spirit of the question.  Given the rest of the method/class, one could make it generic and use `OfType<T>`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize he needed a generic purpose solution. I was thinking only about his solution